# Show Recently commented posts, no duplicate post should show

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have a table from where i want to get the latest commented comment, but when i use group by function its showing me incorrect..
I don't want to show the duplicate records

Below is table and query..

```
SELECT * FROM `dev_web_comments` GROUP BY rID
```

The result i am getting through this query is below, but i want that for rID 41 latest comment should be displayed. Like latest comment is "**THIS IS TESTING**"

[image]

ORIGINAL TABLE IS BELOW

[image]

Comment: `ORDER BY cDate DESC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Danielius I don't want only 1 record.. i want the latest commented records with no limit, when i add group by its not displaying on latest commented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join itself and return the max date. It also works with most recent ID.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dev_web_comments AS d1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT rID, MAX(cDate) AS maxDate
    FROM dev_web_comments 
    GROUP BY rID) AS d2 ON d2.rID = d1.rID AND d2.maxDate = d1.cDate 
GROUP BY d1.rID
```

You can order by whichever field you want.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you can obtain the `cID` value for the latest comment for each distinct `rID` value like this:

```
                        SELECT MAX(cID) cID, rID
                          FROM dev_web_comments
                         GROUP BY rID
```

This is based on the assumption that each new comment is represented by a line inserted to the table, and that the `cID` column is an autoincrementing column.

That means you can obtain the details of the latest comment for each `rID` like this

```
    SELECT a.cID, a.rID, a.wID, a.commentContent, a.cDate, a.wwID
      FROM dev_web_comments
      JOIN (
                        SELECT MAX(cID) cID, rID
                          FROM dev_web_comments
                         GROUP BY rID
           ) b ON a.cID = b.cID
```

The query in your question shows that you're in danger of stumbling into the notorious MySQL `GROUP BY` pitfall. Don't do that. Read this.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html